# removing querystring from current page url in javascript

Tags: javascript, .net

I want to remove querystring from my current page url in javascript on button Click 
can u pls help me with the above code.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
var query = window.location.href.match(/^(.*)\?/);
if (query){
    history.pushState(null, "", query[1]);
}
```

Comment: @user1619874 this will only work in browsers that support pushState, i.e. not ie

Comment: You are a genius !! I have gotten tired of people telling me it is not possible and your solution works like a charm !! This answer should be accepted !! Hope my Upvote helped at least ! Thanks man!!

Answer (score 2):

You cant simple remove query string without redirection or reloading the page . So u will be changing the location or redirecting by using windows.location .
getPathFromUrl() function remove the query-string from given URL.

Here is example how can u do it :

```
function getPathFromUrl(url) {
  return url.split("?")[0];
}

var testurl='http://localhost:2314/RewardPointsSystem/Admin/PointCalculations.aspx?date=20-Sep-2012%22'

window.location=getPathFromUrl(testurl); // loads http://localhost:2314/RewardPointsSystem/Admin/PointCalculations.aspx
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, try this:

```
window.location = String(window.location).match(/(.*?)\?/)[1];
```

Or using the example URL in the comments

```
window.location = "http://localhost:2314/RewardPointsSystem/Admin/PointCalculations.aspx?date=20-Sep-2012%22".match(/(.*?)\?/)[1];
```

Comment: Ok, do you have an example I can look at?

Comment: this is the url which i want to modify  "http://localhost:2314/RewardPointsSystem/Admin/PointCalculations.aspx?date=20-Sep-2012"  I want to load my page with url "http://localhost:2314/RewardPointsSystem/Admin/PointCalculations.aspx" when i click on button

Comment: I can't access that location, so it's not an example I can look at.

Comment: This is the local URL...u cant access this...but this is the sample url of my page which i want to modify

Comment: Change url from ...RewardPointsSystem/Admin/PointCalculations.aspx?date=20-Sep-2012 to ...RewardPointsSystem/Admin/PointCalculations.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can just trim the whole string succeeding the "?" sign